# Fill two autocomplete textbox with reference to index of 1st autocomplete in asp .net

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have an issue for autocomplete textbox. I have 2 autocomplete textboxes say customer and customer dept. I want to fill customer dept autocomplete textbox using the value I get from customer autocomplete textbox. I am getting the data from the database in below format.

```
[
   {"id":"001","value":"WOVEN TOPS","value1":"RIVER"},
   {"id":"001","value":"DRESSES & ONESIES","value1":"URBAN"},
   {"id":"001","value":"SOFT WOVEN","value1":"WAREHOUS"}
]
```

Please help to achieve this.

Comment: According to data provided by you, what would be the customer and dept ??. Well fire query like it gives customer with dept so by split you can set both values  ie cus/dept depend on 1st autocomplete selection

Comment: customer is one textbox and  customer dept is another. As per selection of 1st textbox 2nd should get populated.

Comment: on 1st autocomplete `select` set focus for 2nd and fire autocomplete for 2nd textbox having `minlenth=0`

Comment: Can you please provide me an example as I am new to JQuery :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`

```
        $('.AutoCompleteField').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "ajax.aspx/GetList",
                    data: "{'term':'" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    success: function (data) { response(data.d); },
                    error: function (result) { alert("When it goes wrong"); }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            focus: function (event, ui) { $('.tbOne').text(ui.item.value); $('.tbTwo').val(ui.item.value1); },
            select: function (event, ui){ $('.tbOne').text(ui.item.value); $('.tbTwo').val(ui.item.value1); }
        });`
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but the value of value1 is the value I can get from 1st textbox. I just need to check selected value of 1st textbox is there in 2nd textbox data.